# Get JSON data from text Area field

Tags: apex, json

Hi I have a text area on a custom Object that contains JSON string.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Mariano",
    "Sex": "Male"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Haley",
    "Sex": "Female"
  }
]
```

I need to map these data to a JSON I am building in Apex:

```
"EmployeeData": [
    {
        "empName": "",
        "empAge": ""
    }
]
```

I need to build it dynamically. If the text area contains 3 employee data, I should be able to pass 3 set of EmployeeData in my JSON as well. Can anybody help? Thanks in advanced

Comment: can we assume values are always of type String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = // your text area field;
List<Map<String,String>> EmployeeData  = new List<Map<String,String>>((List<Map<String,String>>)JSON.deserialize(str,List<Map<String,String>>.class));
```

Take advantage of the JSON.deserialize method... refer to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) for more options.

Comment: From there, you can JSON.serialize(EmployeeData)